# Unknown column '' in 'field list' with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a PHP script to basically update a value in a table. Currently, the value is `NULL`, and is `TEXT`. When I try to set it to a string using PHP, I get this error:

> Unknown column '' in 'field list'

I have no idea what this means, and all of the other StackOverflow solutions for this have not helped.

SQL:

```
UPDATE
    `teacher_accounts`
SET
    `quizzes` = "QUIZ_STRING"
WHERE
    `id` = "TEACHER_ID";
```

Table structure:

```
`id` INT(11),
`email` TEXT,
`full_name` TEXT,
`password` TEXT,
`permissions` TEXT,
`activated` TEXT,
`quizzes` TEXT
```

All are filled in except for quizzes which is currently `NULL`. I've been banging my head on the keyboard for this... I'm sure this is an easy fix, sorry if it is a dumb mistake. Thanks in advance!

Mistri

Comment: Try to remove the single quotes. Using them in phpMyAdmin may work, but using them from PHP might cause problems.

Comment: Using `TEXT` for ever field is extremely lazy. Use `VARCHAR(255)` for anything that doesn't require extended length text, `LONGTEXT` for those.

Comment: Also how are you executing this inside PHP? That query is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run the query directly on mysql ?

In your PHP file try this instead

```
UPDATE
    teacher_accounts
SET
    quizzes = "QUIZ_STRING"
WHERE
    id = "TEACHER_ID";
```

Column names don't have single quotes in SQL inside PHP

Comment: I ran it on MySQL successfully. Your PHP command didn't work as well. Same error.

Comment: Are you using PDO ? Can you give us the PHP snippet ? The problem may come from the PHP connection or the execution of the query...

Comment: Ah, got it fixed. I was literally trying to debug by putting an `if/else` -- just deleted that and it worked. PHP... sigh.